# PHP steps in foreach to create two <td>

Tags: php, html

I want to use `foreach` to fetch an array and create 2 `<td>` in `<table>`.
For example, odd in first `td` and even in second `td`.
Following code does not provide correct result:

```
|------------------|---------------|
|                  |               |
|------------------|---------------|

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <?php   
    $id=1;              
    foreach ($resultM as $value) {
        if ( ($id % 2) == 0 )
            echo "<tr><td><ul class='styledlist'><li style='width:250px;'><a id='{$value['name_mojtahed']}'>{$value['name_mojtahed']}</a></li></td></tr></ul>";
        else 
            echo "<tr><td><ul class='styledlist'><li style='width:250px;'><a id='{$value['name_mojtahed']}'>{$value['name_mojtahed']}</a></li></td></tr>";
        $id++;
    } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: what is the question? i see no questions here.

Comment: Do you want two `<td>`s side by side?

Comment: what would be ur output?

Comment: Does the `$resultM` array hold more than 1 value?

Comment: if you will create one `<td>` in one `<tr>` then how many `<td>` will be created then..?

Comment: You also creating another `<tr>` in the else.

Comment: Remember to close your `<ul>` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($resultM as $i=>$value) : ?>
    <td>
    <?php print $value ?>
    </td>
    <?php if($i%2 == 0 && $i != 0) :?>
    </tr><tr>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```